# use random functions (python)

Tags: python, function, random

I wonder if we can do that in python, let's suppose we have  3 differents functions to processing datas
like this:

```
def main():
  def process(data):
     .....
  def process1(data):
     .....
  def process2(data):
     .....
  def run():
     test = choice([process,process1,process2])
     test(data)
  run()

main()
```

Can we choice one random function to process the data ?
If yes, is this a good way to do so ?

Thanks !

Comment: It should work, so if your real code isn't working, then I suggest you provide a short, complete example that you think should work and isn't.

Comment: are you missing `from random import choice` ?

Comment: The above works.  What's your question?

Comment: Great ! My problem now is i would like to print which one is used :

 .... test = random.choice([process,process1,process2]) 

print "using %s"% (test) 

.... 

using <function process1 at 0x1775410>

 how can i remove the "... at 0x1775410>" Thanks !

Comment: Try `print "using %s" % test.__name__`

Comment: @n00bie: Please do not comment on your own question.  You own the question.  You should update the question.  Please update the question and delete the comment.

Comment: now you should ask how to randomly debug it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent approach (net of some oversimplification in your skeleton code).  Since you ask for an example:

```
import random

def main():
  def process(data):
     return data + [0]
  def process1(data):
     return data + [9]
  def process2(data):
     return data + [7]
  def run(data):
     test = random.choice([process,process1,process2])
     print test(data)
  for i in range(7):
    run([1, 2, 3])

main()
```

I've made it loop 7 times just to show that each choice is indeed random, i.e., a typical output might be something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 9]
```

(changing randomly each and every time, of course;-).

Comment: Great !
My problem now is i would like to print which one is used :
     ....
     test = random.choice([process,process1,process2])
     print "using %s"% (test)
     ....

using <function process1 at 0x1775410> , how can i remove the "... at 0x1775410>"

Thanks !

Comment: Just `print "using", test.__name__`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is!

That the nice thing in Python, functions are first class objects and can be referenced in such an easy fashion.

The implication is that all three methods have the same expectation with regards to arguments passed to them.  (This probably goes without saying).

Comment: You mean `function`, right? A method is a kind of function. In the OP's code process1, process2, and process3 are functions.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work with my example, can you provide one please ? 
thanks !

Comment: @lost-theory, right! I edited accordingly.  `function` is the more generic and and appropriate term here (although this technique does work as well for bound `methods`, which as you said are a special kind of function)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the random number module in python.

```
random.choice(seq)
```

This will give you a random item from the sequence.

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work just like you wrote it, if you add this to the top:

```
from random import choice
```

Or, I think it would be slightly better to rewrite your code like so:

```
import random

def main():
  def process(data):
     .....
  def process1(data):
     .....
  def process2(data):
     .....
  def run():
     test = random.choice([process,process1,process2])
     test(data)
  run()

main()
```

Seeing `random.choice()` in your code makes it quite clear what is going on!